# Method to return the column based on multiple conditions in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, if-statement, multiple-instances

I have a dataframe as below. Based on few conditions, I need to retrive the column.

```
    Wifi_User1      Wifi_User2      Wifi_User3      Thermostat   Act_User1   Act_User2  Act_User3
    -58             -48             -60             18              0               1           0
    -60             -56             -75             18              0               1           1
    -45             -60             -45             18              0               1           1
    -67             -45             -60             18              1               0           1
    -40             -65             -65             18              1               0           1
    -55             -78             -74             18              1               0           0
    -55             -45             -65             18              1               0           0
    -67             -45             -44             18              0               0           0
    -65             -68             -70             18              0               0           0
    -70             -70             -65             24              0               0           0
    -72             -56             -45             24              0               1           0
    -75             -45             -60             24              0               1           0
    -77             -48             -65             24              0               0           0
```

The conditions are as follows:

```
if (Wifi_User1==Wifi_User2) or (Wifi_User2==Wifi_User3)
  or (Wifi_User3==Wifi_User1) or (Wifi_User1==Wifi_User2==Wifi_User3) 
   and when the thermostat value is changing

then

scan Act_User1, Act_User2, Act_User3 columns for the first instance of 1 
before the thermostat value changes. 

If its Act_user1, return 1 
else if its Act_User2 return 2
else return 3
```

For example, in the above dataset, at 10th row `Wifi_user1 == Wifi_User2` and the thermostat value is changing from 18 to 24.

For this condition, I will scan Act_User1, Act_User2, Act_User3. And see that, the first instance of 1 occurs for Act_User1, hence I need to return the value 1 in the new column for this particular row.

Please help me as how to go about it, as I'm new to Python and exploring python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question, here's how you would transcribe your if statement:

```
wifi_user_equality = (df.Wifi_User1 == df.Wifi_User2) | \
                 (df.Wifi_User2 == df.Wifi_User3) | \
                 (df.Wifi_User3 == df.Wifi_User1)
thermostat_change = df.Thermostat != df.Thermostat.shift(1)
```

Then to return all rows where you have both true:

```
df[wifi_user_equality & thermostat_change]

         Wifi_User1  Wifi_User2  Wifi_User3  Thermostat  Act_User1  Act_User2   Act_User3 
9           -70         -70         -65          24          0        0.0          0.0
```

Or if you only want the index of these:

```
df.index[(wifi_user_equality & thermostat_change)]
```

---

For the second part of your question, it's trickier, but here's a solution:

```
# We add the first index element too
zero = df.index == df.index[0]

# Get the list of index where the condition is satisfied, in reverse order
idx = list(df.index[(wifi_user_equality & thermostat_change) | zero][::-1])

for i, index in enumerate(idx):
    if index > 0:
        # I use a try/except block in case it cannot find an occurrence of 1
        # (all previous act users are 0).
        # Might not be needed in your specific application
        try:
            x= df.loc[idx[i+1]:(index-1), ['Act_User1','Act_User2','Act_User3']]
            col_of_first_1 = np.where(x==1)[1][-1] + 1
        except:
            col_of_first_1 = 'Not Found'
        # Assign to a new column
        df.loc[index, 'Last_Act_User'] = col_of_first_1
```

---

### In action:

I've modified your data in order to have a more complex case:

```
Wifi_User1      Wifi_User2      Wifi_User3      Thermostat   Act_User1   Act_User2  Act_User3
-70             -70             -65             24              0               0           0
-77             -48             -65             24              0               0           0
-58             -48             -48             18              0               1           0
-60             -56             -75             18              0               1           1
-45             -60             -45             18              0               1           1
-67             -45             -60             18              1               0           1
-40             -65             -65             18              1               0           1
-55             -78             -74             18              1               0           0
-55             -45             -65             18              1               0           0
-67             -45             -44             18              0               0           0
-65             -68             -70             18              0               0           0
-70             -70             -65             24              0               0           0
-72             -56             -45             24              0               1           0
-75             -45             -60             24              0               1           0
-77             -48             -65             24              0               0           0
```

Will give `df`:

```
    Wifi_User1  Wifi_User2  Wifi_User3  Thermostat  Act_User1  Act_User2  \
0          -70         -70         -65          24          0          0   
1          -77         -48         -65          24          0          0   
2          -58         -48         -48          18          0          1   
3          -60         -56         -75          18          0          1   
4          -45         -60         -45          18          0          1   
5          -67         -45         -60          18          1          0   
6          -40         -65         -65          18          1          0   
7          -55         -78         -74          18          1          0   
8          -55         -45         -65          18          1          0   
9          -67         -45         -44          18          0          0   
10         -65         -68         -70          18          0          0   
11         -70         -70         -65          24          0          0   
12         -72         -56         -45          24          0          1   
13         -75         -45         -60          24          0          1   
14         -77         -48         -65          24          0          0   

    Act_User3 Last_Act_User  
0           0           NaN  
1           0           NaN  
2           0     Not Found  
3           1           NaN  
4           1           NaN  
5           1           NaN  
6           1           NaN  
7           0           NaN  
8           0           NaN  
9           0           NaN  
10          0           NaN  
11          0             1  
12          0           NaN  
13          0           NaN  
14          0           NaN
```

Comment: Thank you @Julien Marrec. Based on this condition, I need to find the first instance of 1 in Act_User1, Act_User2 and Act_User3 coulmn and return the value 1,2 or 3 in a new column

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to find a way to do that in pandas-way (vectorized) without resorting to a loop. We agree that you are looking for the first 1 in reverse order (going 'up' the table before the thermostat change) right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. So in my example it would be 6th row, for the column Act_User1 where the first instance of 1 occurs going upwards.

Comment: I added a solution

Comment: AttributeError: ("'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'shift'", u'occurred at index 0')

Comment: You can't shift a row.

Comment: For the second phase, when i run on my example 

the 9th row is showing "Not found". But, i need that value to be 1, and the rest 0's in the "Last_Act_User" column

Comment: Yeah need to add the first index element to the `idx`... I'll update again. I checked with your example, it works.

Comment: Thank you so for the help. I have one last query, I have one more condition, where the Wifi_Users are not equal, and the thermostat value is changed. I need to return the minimum value among Wifi_User1, Wifi_User2 and Wifi_User3.
So, if the minimum value is Wifi_User1, then its 1, else 2 or 3 in the same new column created Last_Act_User.

Please let me know how do i go about it, I have found the minimum, but unable to merge these two conditions

Comment: Sorry but I'm done with this question. You keep changing the requirements. It's a simple task, figure it out or open another thread. I'll give you a hint: `np.argmax`

Comment: I have already used the  np.argmax,  its just correlating the above with the new condition is not giving the result i need.